# Analyze + Optimize on InnoDB Tables

Tags: mysql, innodb

Back then when i was working heavily with MyISAM Tables i always had a cronjob which ran

```
~# mysqlanalyze -o database
```

I know that MyISAM benefit from this in certain ways e.g.: fragmentation and whatnot

Now, when running the same command on a databse where the majority of tables is InnoDB i wonder if this "does any good" to the tables and is considered a good practice to do so every now and then or if its rather counter productive. Reading alot of :

```
Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
```

Which sounds expensive with regards to Disk IO / CPU time ?!

would appreciate some input on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html says:

> For InnoDB tables, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is mapped to `ALTER TABLE ... FORCE`, which rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in the clustered index.

This does do some good in cases when you had too much fragmentation. Pages will be filled more efficiently, indexes will be rebuilt, and disk space occupied by the table will be reduced if you use `innodb_file_per_table` (which is the default in recent versions).

It does take time, depending on the size of your table. It will lock the table while it's running. It will require extra disk space while it's running, as it creates a copy of the table.

Doing optimize table on an InnoDB table is usually not necessary to do frequently, but only after you do a lot of insert/update/delete against the table in a way that could result in fragmentation.

`ANALYZE TABLE` is much less impact for InnoDB. This doesn't require building a copy of the table. It's a read-only action, it just reads a random sample of pages from the table and uses that to estimate the number of rows, average size of rows, and it update statistics about the indexes, to guide the query optimizer. This is safe to run anytime, it will lock that table for moment, but that won't be any greater regardless of the size of the table.

Comment: are you sure it locks the table ? the documentation you linked says : "The table rebuild triggered by OPTIMIZE TABLE and performed under the cover by ALTER TABLE ... FORCE is completed in place. An exclusive table lock is only taken briefly during the prepare phase and the commit phase of the operation. During the prepare phase, metadata is updated and an intermediate table is created. During the commit phase, table metadata changes are committed."

Comment: @RonanT You're right, I did an experiment and confirmed I can update a row of a table while the OPTIMIZE TABLE is in progress. It does create a new physical file, but it uses ALGORITHM=INPLACE. This means it's capturing changes in the online alter log file, which has a fixed size limit. I usually ignore Online DDL because of this limitation, so I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother.  InnoDB almost never needs either `ANALYZE` or `OPTIMIZE`; don't waste your time unless you have identified a need.

An exception is a `FULLTEXT` index on an InnoDB table.  Such can benefit from `DROP INDEX`, then `ADD INDEX`.

If you are "reloading" the table from new data, then the following avoids downtime:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
load `new`
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;   -- fast, atomic
DROP TABLE old;
```

(Caveat:  The above technique probably has issues if there are `FOREIGN KEYS`.)

Comment: I have a script which runs every day and TRUNCATES and then re-populates a full-text InnoDB table.  I noticed today performance had slowed to > 1 second per query.  A quick OPTIMIZE and it's back to 0.4 seconds, so the script now runs OPTIMIZE after the re-population every day.

Comment: @Codemonkey - I add a couple more tips to my Answer.